# gnuplot number of arguments in function

Tags: function, arguments, gnuplot

I made any function with 13 arguments in gnuplot like that

r2adr(c,h,t,p,s,e2,e3,b,b2,ele,ele2,d,d2)

When I run gnuplot , the error was occured.
 line 146: function contains too many parameters
When I decrease the aruments by 12, it was fine.

My question is how I can increase the number of arguments?
Does it need to compile in source level or is any gnuplot command available?

Thanks,

Comment: this doesn't exactly solve your problem, but is a criticism of your problem solving style. I think it would be worthy to restructure the code so that you use less arguments per function. I would run a do loop about one of the arguments or just make a compound function out of many small functions that would eliminate the need for a few arguments. This also makes things very readable.

I could have demonstrated the principle of refactoring this waywere there a minimal example - but I suspect a function with twelve arguments has to be giant. So not looking forward to that! ;)

Comment: Thanks for you comment, you're right. this way is not good for a structural code. I agree your sayings.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, 12 is the limit. I don't think there is an easy way to change that. I think you just have to reduce the number of arguments e.g. by using some constants or passing functions as arguments:

instead of this function with 4 arguments:

```
gnuplot> f(a1,a2,a3,a4)=(a1*a2)/(a3*a4)
gnuplot> plot f(x,1,2,3)
```

you write the same function with 2 arguments:

```
gnuplot> b1(a1,a2)=a1*a2
gnuplot> b2(a3,a4)=a3*a4
gnuplot> f(b1,b2)=b1/b2
gnuplot> plot f(b1(x,1),b2(2,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

If some arguments correspond to a column in a data file with a know column number, your function can use `column` to access them without passing them as parameters.

E.g., instead of

```
f(x,y,z,a)=x*y/z**a
plot for [a=1:2] "f.gdat" using 1:(f($1,$2,$3,a)) title "a=".a
```

you can do:

```
COL_X=1
COL_Y=2
COL_Z=3
f(a)=column(COL_X)*column(COL_Y)/column(COL_Z)**a
plot for [a=1:2] "f.gdat" using 1:(f(a)) title "a=".a
```